# Set intervals equitably for your data (aprox same numer of vales per interval) or at least one value

Tags: r, intervals, frequency

I have a set of samples (rows) that have each a frequency value (from 0.0 to 1.0). `seq` function used to set intervals for these frequencies but the intervals are fixed and there are a lot of them with 0 events: `cut(df$frequencies, breaks=c(seq(0,0.4,0.02), seq(0.5,1,0.1)))`

How can be intervals be set based on the values? That means that intervals have the same number of values (aprox.) or at least one value, i.e. intervals with >= 1 and non-0 values.

Comment: Take a look at the `quantile` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two possibilities, both using a library of mine.

```r
library(santoku)
chop_equally(df$frequencies, groups = 10) # 10 interval of equal size
# or
chop_n(df$frequencies, n = 5) # 5 members in each interval
```